# MySQL Cannot connect via remote php script access

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with MySQL, using PHP PDO on CentOS 7. I'm able to connect to the MySQL database via my script on localhost, on the dedicated serverside, An when tested through a separate dedicated VPS ssh console, I'm able to connect remotely to the MySQL database using `mysql -h 66.xxx.xxx.xxx -P 3306 -u user -p`. Though when attempting to use my script remotely, It gives a database failed to connect error. The script works fine on localhost, as well as the Remote SSH/SHELL console. Ports are open on the remote site, and MySQL is bound to 0.0.0.0 (`bind-address=0.0.0.0`). I have even set the MySQL users with the website IP as host, an even left host at %. I granted the user full permissions to the table.

Shell output: `netstat -nltp | grep 3306` `tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1409/mysqld`

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Here's the script that I'm using:

```
class ConfigWrapper
const DB_HOST = "66.xxx.xxx.xxx";
const DB_NAME = "zxsf";
const DB_USER =  "root";
const DB_PASSWD = "DBPW";`
```

Comment: show us the script

Comment: I edited an added the connect SQL line of the script :)

Comment: That's not the script, that's when you assign values to constants.

Comment: You already look like you know what are you doing but make sure skip-networking is not in your my.cnf or it is commented `#skip-networking`. I can't think about anything else with the data you have provided.

Comment: Alberto I'm new to Stackflow, an didn't know if it was alright to post the entire connect script?(due to the code length, since a notice had stopped me from posting when I was editing.). zebnat - I've also made sure that `#skip-networking` has been commented out as well.. I did do an extensive look up on similar errors, It doesn't seem as if the VPS IP is wanting to pick up the call from any php source unless it's local, Navicat/SSH consoles can connect however remotely. When I ran `netstat -nltp | grep 3306` in shell, it was listening on `tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1409/mysqld`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue,
Fatcow hosting doesn't support scripts being linked to outside mysql remote databases on shared hosting, so selinux is enabled an blocking access..
Thank you all for the help! :)